# Copy parcelable data object

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

How do I copy the parcelable data object I received through an intent from another package to the local object? Of course so that it includes the fields and their values.
Must the parcelable object contain write(dest: Parcel, flags: Int)? I ask because I see the values are saved locally without this method.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a `Parcelable` object from `Intent`, just do this:

```
val parcelableObject = intent.getParcelableExtra("extraKey")
```